# Как убрать надпись "items per page" на гриде?

Tags: angular, kendo

Как убрать надпись  "items per page"  на гриде?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать [CustomMessagesComponent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CustomMessagesComponent/), который перезаписывает текст по умолчанию

```
<kendo-grid-messages pagerItemsPerPage="new text goes here">
```